# Ergonomics of computer code

Tags: ergonomics, code

Earlier I've asked similar question at StackOverflow and was ruthless downvoted. Yet I believe  it to be absolutely viable and useful. At least for me as a software developer.

There are many holy war discussions concerning code style, readability and so on.
Yet the only book which references real ergonomic research I've read so far is Human Factors (6 volumes in Russian translation) by Salvendy. That's too little. I doubt persuasiveness should be based on subjective perception of readability.

Consider these pieces of code:

```
if (bla-bla) return;

if (very-long-bla-bla-bla) return;

if (bla-bla) 
    return;

if (bla-bla)
{
    return;
}

if (bla-bla){
    return;
}
```

Semantically equivalent but from the point of readability is quite different.
When I scan code I usually look at the left side of the screen and expect control flow statements to appear there so it is possible to miss 'return' in first two examples. And it really happens from time to time when I read other developers code.
Well, the research states that vertical scan is more performant than horizontal when width is not too small. But how to compare indented *return* and *return* surrounded with braces?

Another my concern is short term memory and visible part of the routine. If code introduces many 'things' (remember those 7+-2) I prefer to see all of them at once without scrolling back and forth in order to remember what something is used for.
Hence, reasonable to ask if portrait display orientation is better than landscape?

Each programming language has its idioms and code formatting conventions but I never saw the justification for adopting and preferring one to the other.
I appreciate if someone share his knowledge and provide some useful links to the results of scientific research in this subject. Thanks.

p.s. I'm sure it is legal to treat the developers reading my code as users and the result of this process as their experience. ;)

**Update:**

I disagre with the comments stating that this question is about readability only. Absolutely not.
I can continue with examples of language design:
The famous C/C++ '==' and '=' operators and special style `if (value == variable)`  for checking the euality against constant values. Still leaving place for errors when comparing variables.
It is a matter of how easily a mistyping can introuduce hard to spot error.

Another example is API design in general.
In C# `List<T>` could contain only one overloaded `Add` method accepting either `T` or `IEnumerable<T>` then the following code would be possible:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    list.Add(items); // may be item?!
}
```

but `List<T>` has `Add()` and `AddRange()`.

We heavily use the help of autocompletition - sometimes it misleads us and sometimes the error is left unnoticed by developer and compiler as well.

Dynamic languages.
Whenever you use `dynamic` in C# you should forget about IntelliSense, it just doesn't work. It probably could be helpful with some powerfull analysis but it doesn't.
So does dynamic language demand higher load on memory?

Another question is whether programming language and native natural language / culture interfere with each other. Starting from read write direction and finishing with semantics perception.
In Russuian books 'Stream' and 'Thread' are often translated as the same word: '*поток*'. In some literature 'I/O' (*ввода/вывода*) из аdded to the 'Stream' to distinguish from 'Thread'. I do not know whether it influences the comprehension but I suspect it is at least at the stage of learning.

**Update 2**

These videos partially address my question:

http://vimeo.com/97329157

http://vimeo.com/97471514

Comment: IMHO it's not a question for neither StackOverflow nor UX (as reading source code is not typically considered to be a part of user experience, personally I think your postscriptum is bit of a stretch ;)). Programmers StackExchange is probably the right choice, though code style matters have been discussed to death there. My 2 cents on this very subject: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/112723/29029

Comment: @Morawski: but reading code __is__ part of the developer's user experience. My user experience of reading code is greatly affected by having a coding standard (whichever standard is decided on) and everybody adhering to it. Or perhaps I should say my user experience of reading code is greatly affected by code not adhering to the standard that was agreed upon.

Comment: @MarjanVenema I can read a novel in PDF, and then you can say that reading this novel becomes a part of my user experience (while I'm using eg. Foxit Reader), but does it mean that creative writing questions, too, fall in the scope of UX? : ) What doesn't, then?

Comment: @Morawski, yes the pdf is part of the user experience, no creative writing isn't. Your analogy isn't a bit off though. The pdf's role in your user experience goes beyond the formatting changes needed to accommodate the platform. The platform (e-reader/screen as opposed to paper) itself plays a big role. More importantly, while reading and writing a novel are two separate actions (usually by different individuals), reading and writing code are very closely related as most code is read more than written and you cannot write (new) code without reading what is already there. Though it could be...

Comment: @Morawski ...argued that when writing a novel formatting of the text may play an important role in relocating specific passages, I think that role is in an entirely different league from the role code formatting plays in understandability of code (and thus in the user experience of reading code). It does merit some research, though it will probably be difficult to get insights from that. Thanks for the link by the way, interesting read.

Comment: Is there an answerable question here? It seems like a broad discussion.

Comment: @MarjanVenema - thanks... In my view, the way the program (be it IDE or PDF reader) presents the document to you - does count as user experience, of course. The way the coder wrote the program, or the way the writer wrote the book, however - does not, unless we're really stretching definitions for the sake of an intellectual exercise etc.

Comment: @Morawski As to reading a novel. MS Word can provide some metrics about genreal text complexitiy and how educated reader should be to easily understand the contents. It's harder to read Dostoevskii and Tolstoy rather than Chehov. Style matters.

Comment: I also think this is a serious and interesting part of HCID - code readability is critical for programmers. It is as valid as asking what is the optimal length of a line of text? Or how many words in the title of a search result are most effective (answer: 7 ). This topic is little researched and in fact on of the topic I'd like to research in the near future. I don't really see it off-topic. It is much more important than many other questions posted on this forum.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Programming semantics, which belongs to Programmers.SE

Comment: There's not a clear question here. I also believe you are asking about readability, which one could consider part of ergonomics, but I don't think using 'ergonomics' in the title is completely applicable here.

Answer (score 4):

Convention (in whatever context you're working in) trumps all. Whatever your working group has decided upon should be observed. If you're in the process of determining coding conventions there's plenty of good anecdotal, language specific, advice available on the internet.

I know of no studies that suggest a specific coding style is easier to read than others, but as mentioned there is much anecdotal evidence/opinions on the subject, and it's usually language specific.

For instance Javascript looks somewhat like C/Java but has some semantics C/Java programmers wouldn't expect:

```
return {
    x : "x"
};
// in not semantically the same as
return
{
    x : "x"
};
// search for "semicolon insertion gotchas" for explanation
```

I suspect in this area of determining which coding convention is "best", expert experience would tend to yield more useful information than empirical studies. Exactly why I feel this way, I can't say - it's really just a guess. Maybe there are just too many variables for a study to control.

I gave this question a +1 because (even though the question is vague) programming language syntax (and semantics of course) *is* a UX problem, and an often ignored one.  Too many computer languages are using 40 year old syntax. The UX of programming is too repressed. Not always repressed (e.g. Python), but the inertia (especially web languages) seems to be going the wrong way.

Comment: I disagree with the view provided. First, there is no real convention - as a programmer, you'll see a multitude of code styles - it is hard to find two companies that adhere to the same guideline. Second, I believe that in UX the whole point is to improve things, even if the users are already well accustomed to a flawed design.

Comment: Could you please clarify 'UX of programming' and Python as example. What do you mean?

Comment: @voroninp - Python abandoned traditional (C inspired) syntax and gave whitespace (indentation) a syntactical significance.  This means (among other things) there's less room for different formatting styles and it's (arguably) easier to read.

Comment: @izhaki - I didn't mean to imply there's a real convention (unless of course if it's formally specified, and then it's not a convention).  There's expert commentary on conventions readily available, and there are languages that try not to rely so much on convention.

Answer (score 2):

My answer will not be complete - bits and pieces really, I just want to hint at two aspects that I feel are worth not overlooking.

(As I noted in comments, I've shared a few thoughts on the subject before - [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/112718/are-there-any-scientifically-rigorous-studies-of-coding-style-principles/112723#112723)).

> When I scan code I usually look at the left side of the screen and
>   expect control flow statements to appear there so it is possible to
>   miss 'return' in first two examples. And it really happens from time
>   to time when I read other developers code. Well, the research states
>   that vertical scan is more performant than horizontal when width is
>   not too small. But how to compare indented return and return
>   surrounded with braces?

Surrounding it with braces is a habit that helps to protect yourself against introducing a bug.

Let's say you need to call `stream.Close();` before leaving the method. Here's our code:

```
if (bla-bla) 
    return;
```

Okay, let's insert `stream.Close`:

```
if (bla-bla) 
    stream.Close();
    return;
```

And oops, I just broke it. Only calling `stream.Close` is now dependent on whether bla-bla was true. `return` is not conditional anymore, so we'll jump out of the method in any case and the code below will never execute.

Had our code looked like this:

```
if (bla-bla)
{
    return;
}
```

It couldn't happen.

I think it draws attention to an important point. In case of code, which tends to be edited a lot, it's not just about "static" readability.

It's also about **ensuring that this readability is persistent and less likely to get affected by future changes, refactoring etc.**

> Another my concern is short term memory and visible part of the
>   routine. If code introduces many 'things' (remember those 7+-2) I
>   prefer to see all of them at once without scrolling back and forth in
>   order to remember what something is used for. Hence, reasonable to ask
>   if portrait display orientation is better than landscape?

It makes me think of another important aspect: source control.

Programmers don't only read code in code editors / IDEs. Working with source control is essential. The longer code lines are, the harder it gets to keep track of changes, to compare code, to merge changes automatically.

If your code looks like this:

```
if (header instanceof TextView) ((TextView) header).setText(data.getTitle());
```

It's only one line, all right. You saved some vertical space. But now the probability that two programmers change the same line (one renamed `header` to `mainHeader`, another one had to change `getTitle` to `getDescription`) increased, and source control will not be able to tell how to combine these changes automatically, and the developer - which may be a third person - has to resolve the conflict manually.

If the same code was laid out in multiple lines as follows:

```
if (header instanceof TextView) {
    String title = data.getTitle();
    ((TextView) header).setText(title);
}
```

It wouldn't have been a problem. One developer modified lines 1 and 3, the other - only line 2.

So this is another important aspect: **readability in the VCS / diff.** It is much harder to struggle with messy code when resolving conflicts: there may be dozens of such cases at once (and you can't move on until you solve them all), each in a different file so you don't know the context etc.

Then there's also readability when debugging - eg. if four method calls are squashed into one line, it's less convenient for me to debug it step by step...

So, to sum up, there are different contexts in which one approaches code, and this is something one should be aware of when attempting to evaluate its readability.

Comment: Somewhat related article about changes understanding by MS Research: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/groups/sa/howdosoftwareengineersunderstandcodechanges_fse2012.pdf

Comment: The bugs introduced by discrepancies between indentation and actual code flow can be avoided in the language design. For example in python code blocks are determined by indentation, so you couldn't introduce that particular bug in python. (There are other classes of bugs which are possible in python but not in many other languages including C.)

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer about any usefulness in sense of code, but there surely can be some methods to improve code for perception. You should simply think about the code as the written product, that is read by human user (i.e. another programer or someone else), so among others, answer yourself to these questions:

1. Who is the reader of code? Is it you, the author? Amateur programer or expert?
2. How can you help to the reader to better understand the code, it's goals, tasks it solves and tricks it uses?
3. Is there some kind of mentioned in the answer above conventions, that are probably well known among other users and support some standards — in variable names, code formatting, etc.?
4. Do you embed in your code smooth descent from common, "bird's eye view" description of code structure and organizaton to explanations of local, concrete points (for instance, in comments, or in general descriptions)?

Answering these questions is good to feel and understand the code as the *product being used*, so you'll certainly find better solutions in commenting, organization, readability and so on to make it more usable.

Comment: There is a problem with conventions. I suspect that motivation can suffer if they're set authoritatively without conscious acceptance by all team members. On the other side the larger the team the more tastes diverge. I tend to persuade with robust facts because I believe understanding leads to awareness and involvement.